# Array not populating: Incorrect use of add method?

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist

In my `for-loop` below I am trying to add all `car IDS` associated to a `persons` with a certain status.

My code compiles and runs, however the size of arrayList: `listOfCarIds` is remaining **0**. I.e. nothing seems to be added

Is there a mistake in how I am implementing this?

```
for(int i=0 ; i < personsWithStatus.size() ; i++)
{
  idOfCarRelatingToPerson = personsWithStatus.get(i).getCarId();

  List<String> listOfCarIds = new ArrayList();

  listOfCarIds.add(idOfCarRelatingToPerson);
}
```

Comment: You are creating a new `listOfCarIds` in each iteration and discarding it. Perhaps you intended to initalise  the *field* not the local variable before the loop.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Declare your `ArrayList` outside as the ArrayList you have declared inside the for loop will initialize every time and has the scope within the for loop only.

```
  List<String> listOfCarIds = new ArrayList();
for(int i=0 ; i < personsWithStatus.size() ; i++) {
       idOfCarRelatingToPerson = personsWithStatus.get(i).getCarId();
       listOfCarIds.add(idOfCarRelatingToPerson);
            }
```

Comment: Why is this the case?

Comment: @java123999 Every time you are looping through the list in your code, you are declaring a new list and adding that item to it. After the loop completes, the list has gone out of scope and in inaccessible.

Comment: @java123999 I have added a more description, to make you understand

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring your ArrayList in the loop. Each time it goes through the loop it resets listOfCarIDs to a blank ArrayList.

Declare the ArrayList outside the loop, and only use the loop to add to it.